# While loop in shell script get error : too many arguments

Tags: unix, sh

I'm trying to run a very simple script that reads input from a user and continuously loop.But they show error [:too many arguments

```
i=0
while [ $i -le 5 ]
do
echo $i
i='expr $i + 1'
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Change '' to Acute (`). I have tested it works fine

```
i=0
while [ $i -le 5 ]
do
echo $i
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: What's a "teldi"? If you meant to write "tilde", then that's another character: the `~`.

Comment: oh yeah thanx.. I meant Acute( ' ) not tilde

Comment: Actually it is, if anything, a grave accent rather than an acute accent. Whether or not the grave accent and the back-quote are the same character or not is subject to some debate.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you're using single-quotes instead of back-quotes for your command-substitution. In other words, it should be `` i=`expr $i + 1` `` rather than `i='expr $i + 1'`.

Also, an @Pankrates points out, it may be more readable to use the equivalent expression `i=$(expr $i + 1)`. Had the author of whatever material you were reading used that form, it seems safe to say that your troubles had been avoided, at least.

Comment: or preferably replace the outdated backticks with `$()`

Comment: @Pankrates Do you have any reason for saying that backticks are "outdated"? It may or may not be argued that `$()` is more readable (and I'll edit in a note on this, thanks), but I haven't heard anything about them being considered obsolescent.

Comment: You are correct, both methods are still supported (and POSIX compliant) but `$()` has become the more preferable option because of its better nestability. [see this bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)